# Polynomial equations defining a pencil of cubics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $C_1, C_2$ be two distinct cubic curves in $\mathbb{P^2}$ with $F_1, F_2 \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$ the homogeneous cubic polynomials
generating the vanishing ideals of $C_1$, respectively $C_2$. We form a pencil $X \subset \mathbb{P^2} $ generated
by $C_1$ and $C_2$; in detail the pencil is defined as the union

$$  X = \bigcup_{[\lambda: \mu] \in \mathbb{P}^1} V(\lambda F_1 + \mu F_2)  $$

of subschemes $V(\lambda F_1 + \mu F_2) $ in $\mathbb{P^2}$ running over $\mathbb{P}^1$.

My question is if it possible to describe $X$ explictly by vanishing polynomials, respectively the associated ideal sheaf generated by these?

Say for example that subschemes $X_1,..., X_n \subset  \mathbb{P^2}$ are defined by vanishing polynomials $F_1,..., F_n \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$. Then the scheme $X_1 \cup... \cup X_n \subset \mathbb{P^2}$ is associated with polynomial $F_1 \cdot F_2 \cdot ... \cdot F_n$. (More generally if $X_1,..., X_k \subset  \mathbb{P^2}$ where each $X_i$ is defined by vanishing polynomials $F_{i,1}, F_{i,2},..., F_{i, m(i)}$, then the subscheme $X_1 \cup... \cup X_k\subset \mathbb{P^n}$ is associated to the vanishing polynomials $ F_{1, i_1} \cdot F_{2, i_2} \cdot ... \cdot F_{k, i_k}$.)

The problem with pencil $X$ is that it is not a finite union or subschemes, therefore the product of all $\lambda F_1 + \mu F_2$ is meaningless. Are there techniques known to determine the vanishing ideal of $X$?

This problem arise naturally when one wants to blowup $X$ in certain points, since it requires knowledge of the structure sheaf of $X$. see also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433598/calculate-blowup-of-a-pencil-of-cubics-by-hand)  question for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider $X$ as a subset of $\mathbb{P}^2$ then $X = \mathbb{P}^2$ (because for any point of $\mathbb{P}^2$ there is a pair $(\lambda,\mu)$ such that $\lambda F_1 + \mu F_2$ vanishes at that point).

Comment: hmmm yes your argument makes of course sense but this leads
to the confusion where the pencil should naturally "live". 
If more generally $X$ is a scheme, $D_1, D_2 \subset X$
two effective divisors, and one forms "the pencil" of $D_1$ and $D_2$, where 
this object by standard terminology should live if there nothing
said explicitely about it's environment?

As subscheme in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times X$ or in $X$ as 
union 
$\bigcup_{[\lambda: \mu] \in \mathbb{P}^1} V(\lambda D_1 + \mu D_2)$ as
what I thought? (the example above is I.5.1 from Mirandas The basic theory of elliptic surfaces)

Comment: In your particular case the natural ambient variety is the product $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. In the more general situation  of two divisors $D_1,D_2 \subset Y$ the natural ambient variety is the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y(D_1) \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y(D_2))$.

Comment: so you mean that 
$\mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y(D_1) \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y(D_2))$
*generalizes* the concept of a natural ambient variety of 
a pencil constructed from two divisors
$D_1,D_2 \subset Y $? In which sense? In 
backward compatible way? Namely, say
 $Y= \mathbb{P}^2$
like in my case, (or more generally $Y= \mathbb{P}^n$).
Then we have two natural candidates

Comment: for "the ambient space" of the pencil formed by $D_1$ and $D_2$: on one hand $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ containing the pencil as vanishing subscheme of polynomial $X_0 \cdot F_1(Z) + X_1 \cdot F_2(Z)$ 
and on the other hand $\mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y(D_1) \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y(D_2))$.
Are they in this case somehow related to each other?

Comment: If $D_1$ and $D_2$ are linearly equivalent, then $\mathcal{O}_Y(D_1) \cong \mathcal{O}_Y(D_2)$, hence $$\mathcal{O}_Y(D_1) \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y(D_2) \cong (\mathcal{O}_Y \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y) \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y(D_1),$$ hence $$\mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y(D_1) \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y(D_2)) \cong \mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y) \cong Y \times \mathbb{P}^1.$$

Comment: I see. That's funny, since this shows also that
$\mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y(D_1) \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y(D_2))$ is nothing
but the blowup of $Y$ along $D_1 \cap D_2$ even in this general setting. Thank you 
for the explanations!

Comment: No, it is not the blowup, it is only a natural ambient variety for it; the blowup itself is a hypersurface in this projective bundle.

Comment: The blowup is in this situation is the projectivization $\mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y(D_1 \cap D_2))$, so the inclusion of the blowup as hypersurface of $\mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{O}_Y(D_1) \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y(D_2))$ is determned on level of $ \mathcal{O}_Y$-modules by surjective map $\mathcal{O}_Y(-D_1) \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y(-D_2) \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{O}_Y(-D_1) + \mathcal{O}_Y(-D_2) = \mathcal{O}_Y(-(D_1 \cap D_1))$ of ideal sheaves induced by "multiplcation" $\mathcal{O}_Y \oplus \mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathcal{O}_Y$? Is this way of thinking about the blowup inside the ambient space correct?